# How to substring a phrase in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a Phrase like this:

```
DECLARE @helloworld NVARCHAR(100),@partHello NVARCHAR(10)
SET @helloworld='HelloWorld=10&HelloSQL=20'
```

I want to take the number between '=' and '&' , I used this statement but it didn't work ... it returns:

```
10&
```

here is the code I used:

```
DECLARE @helloworld NVARCHAR(100),@partHello NVARCHAR(10)
SET @helloworld='HelloWorld=10&HelloSQL=20'

SET @partHello = 
SUBSTRING(@helloworld,CHARINDEX('=',@helloworld,0),CHARINDEX('&',@helloworld,0)-CHARINDEX('=',@helloworld,0))
PRINT @partHello
```

I want it to be dynamic.. If there is a number bigger than 10, then it will take all the number. I want it to start from '=' and end at '&'

any help?

Comment: Put -1 in 3rd parameter: `CHARINDEX('&',@helloworld,0)-CHARINDEX('=',@helloworld,0) - 1`

Comment: how can i start from the number after the = ?? @PawełDyl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @partHello = 
SUBSTRING(@helloworld,CHARINDEX('=',@helloworld,0)+1,CHARINDEX('&',@helloworld,0)-(CHARINDEX('=',@helloworld,0))-1)
PRINT @partHello
```

Comment: If the first number after the '=' is not 1 ... I want to make it dynamic to take any number that comes after the '='

Answer (score 3):

I would use following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@helloWorld,
   CHARINDEX('=',@helloworld,0)+1,
   CHARINDEX('&',@helloworld,0)-CHARINDEX('=',@helloworld,0)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the solution :

```
DECLARE @helloworld NVARCHAR(100),@partHello NVARCHAR(10)
SET @helloworld='HelloWorld=320&HelloSQL=20'

   SET @partHello = 
SUBSTRING(@helloworld,CHARINDEX('=',@helloworld,0)+1,CHARINDEX('&',@helloworld,0) -(CHARINDEX('=',@helloworld,0)+1))
PRINT @partHello
```